Почему Zabbix Server не подключается к Zabbix Agent на Windows?
Пытаюсь настроить Zabbix Server на виртуалке Debian. Установил Zabbix-агент на физический Windows. Виртуалка на этом же устройстве. При создании узла на сервере прописал адрес физического компа. А в агенте прописал адрес сервера и server-active 127.0.0.1. В логе такая ошибка:

Unable to connect to [127.0.0.1]:10051 [cannot connect to
[[127.0.0.1]:10051]: connection error (POLLERR)].

С виртуалки через терминал подключение по telnet есть.
В чем может быть проблема.
